# apache transfer-encoding chunked enable

Tags: php, ios, rest, upload, chunked-encoding

I have a `RESTFUL` service that receive a huge videos/pictures from iphone/ipad devices,
so we decided to go with `NSURLSessionUploadTask` and this type of uploads uses chunked encoding,

So in my back-end I'm using `PHP` And The server is `Apache 2.4.7`,

But I still cant see the request All `$_POST $_REQUEST $_FILES` are All Empty,

All that I can say that in my headers the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.

So does anybody have a clue what is it an apache config, php issue please help ?

Comment: What have yout tried?

Comment: And what do you get if you read from `php://input` or `php://stdin` ?

Comment: @RagenDazs nothing i have no clue where to start all i know that it was a mod_proxy bug in 2.2 version so i updated to 2.4.7 as it fixed but still nothing

Comment: By default `multipart/form-data` is used as encoding with `NSURLSessionUploadTask`?

Comment: @D.Kasipovic here is the response `input = "";`
 `stdin = "<null>";`

Comment: @RagenDazs i var_dump($_SERVER) heres the response
`"CONTENT_TYPE" = "multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY";`
` "HTTP_TRANSFER_ENCODING" = Chunked;
`

Comment: I do not know anything about NSURLSessionUploadTask, and I am looking at this from purely php/apache side. What I can suggest is that you open port 80 on some machine where you have access, and try to upload there, see what you get from the device, what headers, content, etc. Are you sure your NSURLSessionUploadTask works?

Comment: Than you can use some proxy like Burp Suite to debug your app - set at your iPhone/emulator Burp as your proxy and see the entire http request and compare with Firefox upload for example